# Bound User-Controls in an ObservableCollection aren't showing up in uniformgrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So, I'm fairly new to C#/XAML and have been trying to teach myself MVVM by reworking an old project. I ran into a problem where a user-control is supposed to be added to a uniformgrid. The user-control shows up fine if I implement it by itself, but if I add it to a ObservableCollection and then try to bind that to a uniformgrid, [the path to the user-control gets displayed rather than the actual UI element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBMmA.png). Unfortunately I'm new enough to C# and MVVM that I can't identify what specifically is the problem, which makes it hard to search online for.

```
<UserControl x:Class="CMS.Views.MonthView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CMS.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Dates}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True" Columns="7"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MonthView.cs

```
namespace CMS.Views
{
    public partial class MonthView : UserControl
    {
        public MonthView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MonthViewModel monthViewModelObject = MonthViewModel.GetMonthViewModel();
            this.DataContext = monthViewModelObject;
        }
    }
}
```

MonthViewModel

```
namespace CMS.ViewModels
{
    class MonthViewModel
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<DayViewModel> _dates = new ObservableCollection<DayViewModel>();

        public IReadOnlyCollection<DayViewModel> Dates
        {
            get { return _dates; }
        }

        public static MonthViewModel GetMonthViewModel()
        {
            var month = new MonthViewModel();
            month.testdaymodel();
            return month;
        }

        public void testdaymodel()
        {
            DayViewModel DVM = DayViewModel.GetDayViewModel();
            DVM.LoadDate(DateTime.Now);
            _dates.Add(DVM);
        }
    }
}
```

DayView's XAML which has the DataTemplate

```
<UserControl x:Class="CMS.Views.DayView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CMS.Views" 
    mc:Ignorable = "d"
    MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" BorderBrush="LightSlateGray" BorderThickness="0.5,0.5,1.5,1.5">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Name ="DayBox">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="21"/>
                <RowDefinition  Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="DayLabelRowBorder" CornerRadius="2" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{DynamicResource BlueGradientBrush}">
                <Label x:Name="DayLabel" Content="{Binding Path = Info.Day, Mode = OneWay}" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial"/>
            </Border>

            <!--This will be bound to the event schedule for a given day-->
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DayAppointmentsStack" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: _"I didn't want drown you all in irrelevant code"_ -- no one here wants you to do that either. But that doesn't mean you can post incomplete code and expect an answer. It's your job to write a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, and to provide the necessary details about what you've tried with respect to solving your problem, and what specifically you are having trouble with. See also [ask], and the articles linked at the bottom of that page.

Comment: In the meantime: _"The user-control shows up fine if I implement it by itself, but if I add it to a ObservableCollection"_ -- does this mean you've literally got an `ObservableCollection<MonthView>` object? If so, then that's wrong. Your collection should be of view models, and you should have a `DataTemplate` for that view model type that uses the view object you want (in this case, it sounds like that view object is the `UserControl`, but without a good [mcve] it's hard to tell).

Comment: Peter, which is specifically why I linked the Git repository so that people can view any additional code if I missed something.

Comment: Peter, you can refer back to the question, I added the DayView XAML. I wasn't aware it was necessary for this question. Added the DataTemplate into it.

Comment: _"which is specifically why I linked the Git repository"_ -- using external sources to support your question is harmful to the question and specifically against Stack Overflow standards. And as a matter of policy, many (including myself) won't look at such sources. The point of the MCVE is to ensure people don't have to look at more code than is necessary, and the point of keeping all the code in your question is to ensure that the question always remains valid on Stack Overflow, even if the external source is removed. Every Stack Overflow question needs to be self-contained.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139870/discussion-between-metasyntactic-and-peter-duniho).

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: The same rule applies whether you're using a simple control like a `Label` or your own control like `DayView`.

You need to set the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` that will be bound to each item from your `IReadOnlyCollection<DayViewModel>`.

Then, make a `DataTemplate` of your liking. Like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Dates}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True" Columns="7"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- This control is automatically bound to each DayViewModel instance -->
            <local:DayView />
            <!-- 
            <Label Content="{Binding PropertyToDisplay}" ></Label>
            -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

You didn't show the `DayViewModel` class, so you can just change the `PropertyToDisplay` to the actual property you want your view to display.

EDIT: Making `DayView` the `ItemsControl.Template` will automatically bind it to the `type` of the items in the `ItemSource`.

That means you can treat `DayView` like a `UserControl` with `DayViewModel` as its `DataContext` without explicitly setting it.

I am assuming that the actual `View` of your `DayView` is the `Grid` inside the `DataTemplate`, so I just modified the code as follows:

DayView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="CMS.Views.DayView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CMS.Views" 
    mc:Ignorable = "d"
    MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" BorderBrush="LightSlateGray" BorderThickness="0.5,0.5,1.5,1.5">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <!-- <DataTemplate x:Name ="DayBox"> -->

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="21"/>
                <RowDefinition  Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="DayLabelRowBorder" CornerRadius="2" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{DynamicResource BlueGradientBrush}">
                <Label x:Name="DayLabel" Content="{Binding Path = Info.Day, Mode = OneWay}" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial"/>
            </Border>

            <!--This will be bound to the event schedule for a given day-->
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DayAppointmentsStack" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

    <!-- </DataTemplate> -->

</UserControl>
```

Comment: So, I'm a bit confused by the datatemplate. I'm not displaying a property, but an entire user control. Like, I'm trying to create a grid of the entire view of day, not a single property. Not sure how to display the XAML from DayView within the usergrid as a datatemplate.

Comment: I added in DayView with it's DataTemplate now that I see that's actually part of the problem.

Comment: The items in your `ItemsControl` are `DayViewModel`s, right? Just put the `DataTemplate` you have in `DayView.xaml` into `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`, or put the data template into resources and set its `DataType` property (`DataType="{x:Type vm:DayViewModel}"`. Your `DayView` doesn't have any code-behind, so there is no real need for a separate control.

Comment: The DayView is actually going to have quite a bit of code-behind that just isn't implemented yet, which is why it's being kept separate. Also, dayview will contain appointments, which need their own views. On top of that, monthview is just a panel within a larger application. 

I'm keeping the view separate because it seems like it'll get messy if I don't. I'll play around with setting it as a resource and see if I can get it working but I've never done it before.

Comment: I updated my answer based on the latest information.